# Lambda with different expression returns same output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Take this code snippet for example:

```
a = []
for x in range(2):
    a.append(lambda: print(x))
print(a[0](), a[1]())
```

The output is:

```
1 1
```

But I expected it to be

```
0 1
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: try putting `del x` in between the `for loop` and the last `print statement`. When you are executing lambda it is looking for variable x, which has the latest value as 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use default arguments:

```
a = []
for x in range(2):
    a.append(lambda x = x: print(x))
print(a[0](), a[1]())
```

This works because the default value is evaluated when the function is created. Otherwise all lambda functions will point to the last value of x, which was 1.

Comment: Can you add an explanation of why this works? It will be useful. Abdul has added an explanation why OP's code won't work but It will be useful I think for explaining this.

Comment: @Rahul posted the explanation. Also see Abdul Niyas P M's answer.

Comment: It's basically creating a parameter x and assigning a default value to it, so the equivalent to
>>>lambda x = x: print(x)
is
>>>def someThing(x=x):
          print(x)

Comment: Thanks @sarartur. I guess Avi Shah already knew the answer. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

@sarartur already provided the solution. Here is little more explanation for this behavior.

This is called [Late Binding Closures](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures). Quoting from the blog,

Python’s closures are late binding. This means that the values of variables used in closures are looked up at the time the inner function is called.

So here whenever any of the returned functions are called, the value of `i` is looked up in the surrounding scope at call time. By then, the loop has completed and `i` is left with its final value of 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your `lambda` expressions are printing `x`, but `x` is being updated by your `for` loop, so by the time your `lambda` expressions are invoked, `x` has finished with a value of `1` because that's the last value in `range(2)`.

```py
>>> for num in range(10):
...     pass
...
>>> num
9
```